# Android ADAL not allowed to load local resource

Tags: android, azure, webview, xamarin, adal

Some quick info first:

- The application is being written in c# using Xamarin
- For authentication I use Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory package version 4.0.209160138-alpha (or ADAL in short)
- The backend runs AAD with B2C

The way this works is that azure will present the user with a webview (at least I suspect it's a webview) where he or she can select his preferred method of signing in/up

That all works fine, the user clicks on "log in", ADAL loads the identity providers from the backend (facebook, g+, ...) and when you select one you get the expected sign-in screen from the respective provider.

The problem is that, when the user actually logs in with their social account, the application suddenly returns to the mainscreen.
If i then check the logs I see this error:

```
"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)
```

I know this is a safety feature and that there are ways around this but since everything is being generated inside the ADAL and since I can't access the library's sourcecode to change the webview settings I'll have to do it some other way.
And as far as I'm aware I can't change chromium's global settings either so I'm kinda stuck.

Has anyone else had this issue? Or, even better, know a workaround?
Perhaps I can use an alternative to chromium? (Allthough I'm unsure of how that'd work since I can't edit ADAL's inner workings and it doesn't seem to be open source)

The code used to generate all this is pretty simple (most of it is automated or done inside ADAL):

```
        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Login(IPlatformParameters parameters, bool isSignIn)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL, new TokenCache());

        if (CORRELATION_ID != null &&
                CORRELATION_ID.Trim().Length != 0)
        {
            authContext.CorrelationId = Guid.Parse(CORRELATION_ID);
        }

        String policy = "";
        if (isSignIn)
            policy = EMAIL_SIGNIN_POLICY;
        else
            policy = EMAIL_SIGNUP_POLICY;

        return await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(SCOPES, ADDITIONAL_SCOPES, CLIENT_ID, new Uri(REDIRECT_URL), parameters, UserIdentifier.AnyUser, EXTRA_QP, policy);            
    }
}
```

Edit: tested it on an older version of android (api 15) and there it does work, so it's not the logic of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for whatever freaking reason android decided it's suddenly cool with all of this.

I don't know why but it's working now. I sure as hell didn't change the code...

Answer (score 0):

All versions of ADAL are open source.  You can find the source for this particular version here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/tree/Convergence-v4-RELEASE

Comment: the naming of the project confused me... But it seems to be the right one after all, I'll see what I can do. In the meantime, suggestions remain welcome.